# Implementing 2D Hausdorff distance in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, image-segmentation

I'm trying to use an existing implementation of Hausdorff distance at [Keras-Weighted-Hausdorff-Distance-Loss](https://github.com/danielenricocahall/Keras-Weighted-Hausdorff-Distance-Loss/blob/master/hausdorff/hausdorff.py)
 as lose function for image segmentation inside my compile call
However, I'm getting the error:

> ValueError: in user code:
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py",
> line 878, in train_function  *
> return step_function(self, iterator)
> File "", line 58, in loss  *
> term_1 = (1 / (num_est_pts + eps)) * K.sum(p * K.min(d_matrix, 1))
> ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 65536 and 16384 for '{{node map/while/mul_1}} = Mul[T=DT_FLOAT](map/while/Reshape_1,
> map/while/Min)' with input shapes: [65536], [16384].

The issue; it's not clear what is the expected shape for (y_true, y_pred). My y_true, y_pred shape is [batch, w, h, No of classes ] but I think they expect a shape of [w,h].

***EDIT***

Below is the code from [Keras-Weighted-Hausdorff-Distance-Loss](https://github.com/danielenricocahall/Keras-Weighted-Hausdorff-Distance-Loss/blob/master/hausdorff/hausdorff.py)

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
import numpy as np
from sklearn.utils.extmath import cartesian
import math


def cdist(A, B):
    """
    Computes the pairwise Euclidean distance matrix between two tensorflow matrices A & B, similiar to scikit-learn cdist.
    For example:
    A = [[1, 2],
         [3, 4]]
    B = [[1, 2],
         [3, 4]]
    should return:
        [[0, 2.82],
         [2.82, 0]]
    :param A: m_a x n matrix
    :param B: m_b x n matrix
    :return: euclidean distance matrix (m_a x m_b)
    """
    # squared norms of each row in A and B
    na = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(A), 1)
    nb = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(B), 1)

    # na as a row and nb as a co"lumn vectors
    na = tf.reshape(na, [-1, 1])
    nb = tf.reshape(nb, [1, -1])

    # return pairwise euclidead difference matrix
    D = tf.sqrt(tf.maximum(na - 2 * tf.matmul(A, B, False, True) + nb, 0.0))
    return D


def weighted_hausdorff_distance(w, h, alpha):
    all_img_locations = tf.convert_to_tensor(cartesian([np.arange(w), np.arange(h)]), dtype=tf.float32)
    max_dist = math.sqrt(w ** 2 + h ** 2)

    def hausdorff_loss(y_true, y_pred):
        def loss(y_true, y_pred):
            eps = 1e-6
            y_true = K.reshape(y_true, [w, h])
            gt_points = K.cast(tf.where(y_true > 0.5), dtype=tf.float32)
            num_gt_points = tf.shape(gt_points)[0]
            y_pred = K.flatten(y_pred)
            p = y_pred
            p_replicated = tf.squeeze(K.repeat(tf.expand_dims(p, axis=-1), num_gt_points))
            d_matrix = cdist(all_img_locations, gt_points)
            num_est_pts = tf.reduce_sum(p)
            term_1 = (1 / (num_est_pts + eps)) * K.sum(p * K.min(d_matrix, 1))

            d_div_p = K.min((d_matrix + eps) / (p_replicated ** alpha + (eps / max_dist)), 0)
            d_div_p = K.clip(d_div_p, 0, max_dist)
            term_2 = K.mean(d_div_p, axis=0)

            return term_1 + term_2

        batched_losses = tf.map_fn(lambda x:
                                   loss(x[0], x[1]),
                                   (y_true, y_pred),
                                   dtype=tf.float32)
        return K.mean(tf.stack(batched_losses))

    return hausdorff_loss
```

and this my code to call the above lose:

```
metrics = [sm.metrics.IOUScore(threshold=0.5), sm.metrics.FScore(threshold=0.5), weighted_hausdorff_distance(image_size, image_size, 0)]

model.compile(optimizer=optim,loss= dice_loss_se2,metrics= metrics)

history =model.fit_generator(train_gen, validation_data=valid_gen, steps_per_epoch=train_steps, validation_steps=valid_steps, 
                    epochs=epochs)
```

I got the above error after calling model.fit_generator. I guess the issue with the shape of my y_true and y_pred. ***I don't know what is the required shape.***

Comment: please add some reproducible code, otherwise, it would be hard to spot.

Comment: I added more details under EDIT.

Comment: what is the required shape for y_true and y_pred?

Comment: It expects y_true/y_pred as `batch_size, h, w`. Now, as you've (batch, w, h, No of classes), you may need to do `tf.argmax` to collapse the last channel. However, it's not clear how you're using this loss function as a metric for the segmentation model.

Comment: Thank you very much! .... its working fine now.

Comment: Is there away to calculate Hausdorff distance for each class in Unet instead of the average of say the 4 classes.? so I get 4 values instead of 1

Comment: Check this https://github.com/qubvel/segmentation_models/blob/94f624b7029deb463c859efbd92fa26f512b52b8/segmentation_models/base/functional.py#L73

Comment: Great .... thank you so much!

Comment: if I wanted accuracy instead of lose .. for example, in dice lose , if I want accuracy, I subtracts the lose from one.  How about Hausdorff distance, how to get accuracy instead of lose.

Comment: I'm not sure. Check this, [repo](https://github.com/PatRyg99/HausdorffLoss), [discussion](https://github.com/PatRyg99/HausdorffLoss/issues/2). However, please post new question, it's becoming some chain question here. >-_-<